# Calculate age In Years and Days PHP

Tags: php, date, time, converters, calculation

I know this has been asked many times over the years, but I still get different results than what I  think should be right.  I have the following code that calculates the amount of days between two dates and then it converts it to years and days. When I convert result isn't what I expect. See below. Please let me know what is incorrect, this is really frustrating.

Thanks!

```
$born = '1985-09-09';
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // this is today's date
$birthdate = new DateTime("$born");
$today = new DateTime("$date");

$diff = $today->diff($birthdate)->format("%a");

$days = $diff;
$years_remaining = intval($days / 365); //divide by 365 and throw away the remainder
$days_remaining = $days % 365;    

echo "<b>Age:</b> ".$years_remaining."y-".$days_remaining."d<br />";
```

What I want to appear:
Age: 35y-0d

But what I get:
Age: 35y-9d

Comment: simply make `$days_remaining = 0` don't you think it'll resolve the problem if your sole purpose is to only show the years. And not the Exact year + days?

Comment: is it a coincidence that the born date and current date are `-09` and you're getting 9 days remaining? What happens if you use born as `1985-09-13` and current date as `2020-09-15` for example? Also you can do `new DateTime($born)` - the variables are already strings.

Comment: A year isn’t always 365 days, there were a number of leap days in there (about… 9?).

Comment: Right there were leap years in there, is there a way to do a calculation to take that into account? I thought maybe the PHP functions were.  Obviously not.  I want to show the days.  This is just one example, I just happened to use today's date.

Comment: Yes I just happened to pick today because it's for my basketball site and a player has a birthday today.  But it's wrong by 7 or 8 days for everyone else too.

Comment: Have you checked https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php#115065 and tried outputting it using `->format("%y %d")`? You're currently returning only the number of days and then doing the math yourself to determine the number of years from that.

Comment: I have tried using the %d, but when you convert the age to years and days it still doesn't do it correctly.  %d all by itself works fine yes, but that's not what I want, that's like 12784.

Comment: `$born = '1985-09-13';
$date = '2020-09-15';
$birthdate = new DateTime($born);
$today = new DateTime($date);

$years = $today->diff($birthdate)->format("%y Years");
$days = $today->diff($birthdate)->format("%d Days");
$both = $today->diff($birthdate)->format("%y Years, %d Days");

echo $years."<br>";
echo $days."<br>";
echo $both."<br>";` seems to work correctly for me with the output `35 Years
2 Days
35 Years, 2 Days`

Comment: I think the issue is how I am pulling the two dates from my variables.  Because yeah hardcoding dates in does seem to work.

Comment: Yeah Steven Jones it doesn't work.  Try these two dates.  1984-12-30 and today 09-09-2020.  Nowhere near right.

Comment: The %d is based on using the months %m parameter as well.  I just want years and days...but the days without being connected to months.  So December 30, 1984 should be like 35 year and 250 days or something like that.  Using %d makes it 10 days, because it's based on using the month parameter.  I don't want to use the month parameter, but looks like I might have to.

Comment: It because leap years, you can not devide by 365 and get right result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because leap years contains 366 days you can't just divide days/365:

```
<?php
$born = '1985-09-05';
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // this is today's date
$birthdate = new DateTime("$born");
$today = new DateTime("$date");

// get diff in full years
$diff_years = $today->diff($birthdate)->format("%y");

// add years diff to birthday, (so here your last birthday date)
$birthdate->add(new DateInterval("P{$diff_years}Y"));

// count days since your last birthday party day
$diff_days = $today->diff($birthdate)->format("%a");

echo "Age: ".$diff_years."y and ".$diff_days." days ";
```

[Here you can try live PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=a01973a2d91edbd7c7f607da1cf6ac04&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Thank you so much, that's it!!! Really appreciate !  I just had no idea how to deal with the leap year part of it.